# Cant perform a function when selecting a key value pair from an array

Tags: javascript

I'm making a simple AI chat program. I have a list of questions I can ask, and it gives me an answer based on what I've asked.

----------------------This is my key value pair array---------------------------

```
var dictionary = {
    "HOW ARE YOU?": ["im fine thanks",
                        "Im okayish",
                        "im good, how are you?"

                    ],
    "SUP?" : ["nothing much", "google" window.open("http://www.google.com");]
}
```

how do I select a random output from the array using a random function.

```
var random = parseInt(Math.random() * dictionary[question.toUpperCase()].length); // Returns a random number between 0 and the arraysize

answer = dictionary[question.toUpperCase()][random];
```

Now my problem is, suppose I ask the AI "sup?" it should either show "nothing much", or say "google" and open up google.

But this doesn't work. basically the `window.open()` in that array makes the javascript to crash.

If I change the array to:-

```
"SUP?" : ["nothing much", "google" ]
```

i.e without the `window.ppen()` function, it does work.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try a bit more complex data structure:

```
var dictionary = {
    "HOW ARE YOU?": [{ message: "im fine thanks" },
                     { message: "Im okayish" },
                     { message: "im good, how are you?" }],
    "SUP?" : [{ message: "nothing much" }, 
              { message: "google", 
                action: function() { window.open("http://www.google.com"); }
              }]
}
```

Then you check if a selected answer has an action and invoke it.

```
function randomElem(array) {
    return array[parseInt(Math.random() * array.length)];
}

function getAnswer(question) {
    var answers = dictionary[question.toUpperCase()];
    if (!answers) {
        return { message: "I dont know what you mean!" };
    } else {
        return randomElem(answers);
    }
}

function processInput(question) {
    var answer = getAnswer(question);
    show(answer.message); // replace it with whatever you use to show the answer
    if (answer.action) {
        answer.action();
    }
}
```

Comment: function processInput(question){
 var random = parseInt(Math.random() * dictionary[question.toUpperCase()].length);
 var answer = dictionary[question.toUpperCase()][random];
 
 show(answer.message);
 
 if (answer.action) {
     answer.action();
    }
    else{
     answer = "I dont know what you mean!";
 }        -------------- oops, i dont know why i cant format this, anyway, this is what i did now and answer doesnt have anything stored after this. I think we dont check if the question is available in the dictionary or not

Comment: @Jasim I added a check if there are any answers in the dictionary for given question. Additionally I split the code into smaller functions.

Comment: worked perfectly ! Also now I was planning to extend this to function like a basic AI, for eg:- if the user asks "how you" instead of "how are you" since "how you" is a close match to "how are you" it would print the output as if the user asked "how are you", for this, is using JS a good approach? Im currently an undergraduate student studying CS and BIS, just doing this as a hobby. Would JS be a good option to make an AI program?
I would definitely go with java as the compiler shows the errors, but this var data structure in JS makes stuff soo simple i feel i should stick with it,

Comment: @Jasim I'm not an AI expert but I think that both Java and JS are good enough for this purpose. Do you want to make everything from scratch? I guess that at some point you will need to use a library/framework/etc. Maybe do a small research before to check in what language you can find more "helpers". Keywords that may be useful at this moment: levenshtein distance, full text search.

Answer (score 0):

`"google" window.open("http://www.google.com");` is not a proper JSON value.
Instead you could do something like, 
`if(answer === 'google') window.open("http://www.google.com");`
And have the `dictionary` store just the strings.

Comment: thats initially how i did stuff, but then that meant lots of loops,
hence i decided to split it into an array.
Your solution is fine if the AI is only supposed to open google.

Comment: but what if i had like 50 commands to open different websites, that would make it slower yeah?

Answer (score 0):

try to open google link after you are getting the answer

```
var random = parseInt(Math.random() *   dictionary[question.toUpperCase()].length); 
answer = dictionary[question.toUpperCase()][random];
if(answer=="google"){
 window.open("http://www.google.com")
}
```

Comment: this does work,

but if I create 50 different commands to open different websites, this way would be inefficient, nevertheless it does solve the problem.

have a look at what lukasz gave as an answer, thats exactly what  i was looking for.